# I am not able to see Data Flow Task Plus ext [ Cozyroc SSIS + ( 2.0 Licensed=Trial)] in SSIS Toolbox

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, dataflowtask, cozyroc

The applications I am using on my machine :

1. Visual Studio 2019
2. SQL Server 2016
3. SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 19
4. Cozyroc SSIS+ 2.0 ( Licensed : Trial )

After installing the cozyroc SSIS+ ( Roaming Mode ) , I am not able to see it in SSIS toolbox .
Also when I try installing the Data Flow Task + it redirects me to the main Cozyroc website to download the package .

The solution (.sln) file that I am trying to use requires DFT+ extension .
Tried all possible solutions but none of them are working for me .

My main focus is to bring DFT+ extension .
Any Help will be appreciated .

Comment: Did you find out what was causing this? I'm seeing the same issue with CozyRoc 2.1. It might be something to do with the supported versions https://desk.cozyroc.com/portal/en/kb/articles/cozyroc-recommended-ssdt-versions-for-data-flow-task-plus